# How to recompile my ascx control(Developed using vs 2003 using Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ascx

I have a web control developed using visual studio 2003. We are reusing this control in couple of other projects too( created as dll). 
Now We are planning to add some more functionality to it. I have visual studio 2005 installed into my machine. I tried to open the project in Visual studio 2005, but it didn't worked.

I am not sure, how to create an ascx user control and compile into dll. Can somebody help me or tell me, how can we open or create the web controls using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: What do you mean didnt worked?

Comment: I am not able to open the project itself. When i open it as a website, it is not giving me the DLL.

Comment: in the worst case create a ne wcontrol project in 2005 and import the ascx and the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open the web project as a Web Application, not a WebSite. You may install the Visual Studio 2005 SP1 first, which will add the Web Application template to the visual studio. By default, the Visual Studio 2005 does not have the Web Application template, and the WebSite mode can't be compiled into dll.

Comment: I have recreated the project as Web Application using VS 2008. And it worked.